# Laravel 5.5 redirect to login page after first attempt

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5.5

I have a login form in home, and I'm simply try to redirect the user to login page if the data is wrong.
Here what I tried so far:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/');
        } else {
            return redirect('/login')->withInput();
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

It works only if the data is correct, otherwise I get *ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS*

**The login page works**.

Comment: i guess you have an auth middleware applied on /login  , show routes/& login code

Comment: No @AchrafKhouadja I'm using illuminate/auth routes, not custom ones.
It works if I get to the url without posting any data.

Comment: exclude login route from auth check, otherwise it will check login route also with auth check and try to redirect back to it. that's why you get 'ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS'

Comment: @RavishaHesh you're right. The only problem I have with your solution is that I don't get the errors after login.

Comment: If you are using custom login function you to set auth check error manually usimg withErrord method

Comment: @RavishaHesh I'm not using custom login..

Comment: I your login form is on home why are trying to redirect the request to "login" route?

Comment: Hi @RavishaHesh I'll redirect to the login page, only if the login data submitted in the home is wrong.

Comment: Alright, so that's a special requirement that you can't achieve from the default login funtion, because it will always redirect back to the origin of the request. So what you can do is, you have to override the funtion which validates the input in Auth/LoginController. Instead of using `$this->validate(...)` use `Validator::make(..)` method and if validation fails redirect the request to login route `withInput()` and `withErrors()`

Answer (score 0):

dont use the contrcutor to verify the login details of users
place the auth::check() method in the method